# additional restrictions in a nhibernate join

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to add additional restrictions in a join in hql?

The sql:

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.PersonOrder OP ON OP.ID_PERSON = P.ID AND OP.ID_ORDER = 3
```

Is it possible to get this in hql, linq or queryover?
I have a many to many relation between  *Person* and *Order*. On the left side, I want all Person objects and on the right side, i need null or the order with id 3 (if there is a link between that person and order number 3).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `with` keyword

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.PersonOrder OP WITH OP.ID_ORDER = 3
```